# Ordering R to restart a function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, sample

my problem is strange, I guess. 
I am trying to make a schedule for volleyball teams at my university and I decided I want to do via R. I have 21 teams and 16 of them are playing every week. Doesn't really matter if some teams have different number of games, because we are going to look at the average results.

So I created a very simple function:

`play<-function(group){ 
    for (i in 1:1){
    playing<-sample(group,16)
    in1<-sort(playing)
    in2<-sample(playing)
    if( sum(in1==in2)==0 ){
        games<-rbind(in1,in2)
        }
    if( sum(in1==in2)!=0 ){
    i<-i-1
    }
    }
    return(games)
    }`

What is my problem? R is not helping me! If the two vector in1 and in2 are equal to each other in at least one position, it is not running the function for again. Do you guys have any idea why? Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

Playing are the teams which are playing this week. (Just 16 of them play)
group will be a vector with the name of the teams... (You can use A, B, C, D as an example)
sample(playing) just randomizes the vector with the 16 chosen teams. When in1 and in2 don't match in any space, we can make the pairs for playing. And while checking this, the problem comes. :/

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: `for (i in 1:1)` will only run once, ever. You might want `while`, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this overall.

Comment: Are you trying to make a schedule of 16 games where each of the 16 teams plays two games. In one game the team appears in the first column (playing at home?) and in the other it appears in the second (playing away?)? So you want to generate a permutation of (1:16) such that the `n-th` element of the permutation isn't `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is generally very complicated. Isn't it enough to sample the 16 teams first and then let them play each other? Try this:

```
play <- function(group){
  playing <- sample(group, 16)
  # if you have 16 teams, you really just have 8 games...
  games <- rbind(playing[1:8], 
                 playing[9:16])
  return(games)
}
play(LETTERS[1:21])
```

Answer (score 0):

The permutation of 1:n such that none of the permutation is in the same place is called a "derangement": http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html

So if you have 16 teams, and want to arrange 16 games where each team plays at home and away once and doesn't play itself, you need to compute a derangement.

So search on rdocumentation.org and there's a function in the PerMallow package.

```
install.packages("PerMallow")
require(PerMallow)
```

Then you can generate one derangement (here of size 6) thus, as a one-row matrix:

```
r.derangement(1,6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    4    1    5    3    6    2
```

So for five teams named A to E:

```
> teams = LETTERS[1:5]
> teams
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

you bind the team names with the team names ordered by the derangement, which you get from the first row of the 1-row matrix:

```
> cbind(teams, teams[r.derangement(1,5)[1,]])
     teams    
[1,] "A"   "E"
[2,] "B"   "C"
[3,] "C"   "A"
[4,] "D"   "B"
[5,] "E"   "D"
```